# Cakephp - can i import the model and write the query in app_helper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

Hi I plan to display images in view files through out the site
 so can i import the model and write the query in app_helper file???

Are its a Good format to write find query in app_helper especially in cakephp?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import models anywhere like this:

`App::import('Model','MyModel'); $MyModel = new MyModel();`

However it goes against all CakePHP conventions to directly access models in helpers. It would be more Cake-like to write a Component to do the model imports & queries and a helper to display the results and include the component & helper in your AppController if you want to use it everywhere in your site.